# multiupload vaadin freezes on upload

Tags: vaadin, multi-upload

I am using Vaadin framework 7.4.5 and wcslib-vaadin-widget-multifileupload (2.0.3)
I noticed that most of times, when I try to upload files, the upload status window hangs, though upload gets completed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this also happening on productive server, or only on localhost during development? How large are the uploaded files?

Comment: Try using version 2.1-SNAPSHOT instead of 2.0.3

Comment: Its happening on server as well as local host. The uploaded files at 500mb, but they can be in gb also.

Comment: I dont see any 2.1-SNAPSHOT. I see 2.0.1 , 2.0.2, 2.0.3 and 3.0 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. it has to with using jetty, with older version of this add on.
I upgraded the add on to latest version and vaadin to compatible version and used tomcat and it worked fine, so far.